# How to align input="radio" with their labels?

Tags: css, html, vertical-alignment

I know there are a lot answers here. I searched, tried to adapt but I failed all the time, that is why I am asking now.

I have the following problem. I want, both, labels and there inputs to be in the same line: Yes o No o (o symbolize the input).

Here my following code, remark that I changed the display property of label to inline block:

```html
<div class="col-sm-3">
        <label>Yes</label>
        <input type="radio" name="yes/no" checked>
        <label>No</label>
        <input type="radio" name="yes/no" >
    </div>
```

Sorry for answering, although there are a lot of similar questions and answers but adapting them did just not work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the inputs and the label to be 'bottom-aligned', try using `vertical-align: text-bottom`.

```css
input[type='radio'] {
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}
div {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <label>Yes</label>
    <input type="radio" name="yes/no" checked>
    <label>No</label>
    <input type="radio" name="yes/no" >
</div>
```

Comment: yes, almost! The inputs are a bit below the labels but it helped clearly. How could I fix it?

Comment: @Anna Marie, I updated the answer, could you check it again ? I am now using text-bottom instead of bottom, I also added a small margin

Comment: It works!! I only needed the one property? Crazy :). Thank you! In 2 minutes I mark your answer!

Comment: @Anna Marie, yes you only need vertical-align: text-bottom, then you can add a small margin to adjust if needed

Answer (score 3):

Apply `vertical-align: middle` with `margin-top: -1px` to each input[type='radio'] :

```css
input[type='radio'] {
  margin-top: -1px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <label>Yes</label>
    <input type="radio" name="yes/no" checked>
    <label>No</label>
    <input type="radio" name="yes/no" >
</div>
```

Perfect center : just line added crossing text and button in this second snippet to show perfect center

```css
input[type='radio'] {
  margin-top: -1px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.col-sm-3 {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid;
}

.col-sm-3:after {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background: black;
    top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <label>Yes</label>
    <input type="radio" name="yes/no" checked>
    <label>No</label>
    <input type="radio" name="yes/no" >
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider wrapping your `<input>` in the `<label>` fields.

Example:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <label>Yes
    <input type="radio" name="yes/no" checked>
  </label>
  <label>No
    <input type="radio" name="yes/no" >
  </label>
</div>
```

This implementation will increase accessibility and usability of your inputs and doesn't require any additional css.